# Removing a property from a class which implements <NSCoding> results in 'class not key value coding-compliant'

Tags: ios, nscoding

I have a class which implements ˚ protocol and has the property netAbsAmount. I decided to remove it but now I am getting the following error:

```
[<Person 0xa37b6b0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key netAbsAmount.
```

I think I understand what is wrong but I don't know how to fix it. I am changing my model but it has to work with previous data. So, the old data would have property `netAbsAmount` but the new model does not. In the `initWithCoder` method, the `netAbsAmount` property is not set anyways so I don't see what the problem is. In other words, that is a property that is not used previously and so is not encoded in `encodeWithCoder` during serialization and not initialized at `initWithCoder` during deserialization.

Setting breakpoints and walking through, the crash occurs after `viewWillAppear` but before `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a nib file that has a connection to that outlet?

Comment: No. The Person class has no nib and is a model class.

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint.  Trigger the exception.  Copy the full stack trace and paste it into your question.

Comment: @robmayoff The problem is that I don't know where to set the breakpoint. I set it at viewWillAppear and cellForRowAtIndexPath. That is the root view controller called IouViewController. It passes viewWillAppear fine but then it crashes before cellForRowAtIndexPath. My question is what is after viewWillAppear but before cellForRow. The IouViewController is a regular UIViewController with a UITableView to display the data. Thanks.

Comment: [How to add an exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)

Comment: @robmayoff While using exception breakpoint, I figure out where the mistake is. I was using a sortDescriptor that was using that property and it crashes the app. Thank you.